# Yii runactions not working as it should

Tags: php, yii, background-process

I'm currently trying to user runactions to execute processes (especially long requests) without having the user to wait. So I followed the documentation of [runactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/runactions/). And it says below should work. The insert statement should work while the action would still proceed.

```
public function actionLongProcess(){

        if(ERunActions::runBackground()){
             $sql = <<<EOD
                   insert into public.test (value) VALUES ('hehe')                              
EOD;
             Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

        }else{
                ChromePhp::log('hello');
        }
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't and I don't know why, only the else part is executed. kinda clueless here.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is a helper class for running actions. It makes controller actions reusable within different contexts.

**Features**

Run controller actions as background tasks

Configure cron jobs

'Touch' urls at remote/local servers.

Run preconfigured batchjobs or php scripts

Use builtin Http client for simple GET and POST requests (since v1.1)

Interval filter for controller actions (since v1.1)

**Requirements**

Developed with Yii 1.1.7

*When using 'touchUrlExt' (see below) you have to install the extension* [ehttpclient](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ehttpclient)